# What are the <executables> in a page definition file in Oracle ADF framework?

Tags: oracle-adf

As far as I understood, the bindings in `ADF` the `Pagedef.xml` contains the bindings for a particular JSF page and these bindings are a glue between the UI layer and the business services running at the back end which is abstracted by the `Datacontrol` layer . I want to understand what are the `<executables>` in  pagedef.xml file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executables represent methods that are called from the page - in many cases those are the methods that return collections of data.
More on this here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/web.1112/e16182/bcdcpal.htm#BABIFIBI